# How to handle a file handling code that shows no output after first time?

Tags: python-3.x, file-handling

> with open("E:\Antariksa\LINES.TXT",'r') as ft:
>
> try:
>
> ```
>   while True:             
>
>         s=ft.readline()             
>
>         st=s.split()             
>
>         if len(st)\>=10:                 
>
>                print(s+"\\n")
> ```
>
> except EOFError:
>
> ```
>     print("End of the file. Thank you!!")
> ```
>
> except:
>
> ```
>     print("Some exception occured")
> ```

I wrote this code on Jupyter notebook. It showed the desired output only once. When I tried running the same code in the same cell for the second, third and consequent times, it didn't show the desired output i.e. the code ran but the output wasn't visible. I tried closing the file and running to he code again. This time too it was the same. Then I closed my entire notebook including the Home page. After that when I reopened the notebook and that particular file where this code was, and ran it again, this time it showed the desired output. But just as before the output wasn't visible in the subsequent times. I have to close the notebook again and again to see the output for this code. I tried to use the tell and seek function(although they are specifically meant for binary files and not for text files) and the ftell function to find out the position of the pointer. Still the result was the same, "no output" yet no error in code.

What exactly am I missing here ?

Comment: Don't know for sure, but are you certain, the resulting error is ```EOFError```?

Comment: @itprorh66 I added this statement to handle any Eof error if it occurs. I suppose this has nothing to do with my problem.

Comment: It makes it hard to diagnose exactly what is going on without the code properly formatted. Please fix it based on [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/8508004) where it discussed sharing blocks of code here. Look for where it says about, "Use fenced code blocks by surrounding your code with", and use those. Adding to this is you admit including stuff that has nothing to do with your problem. Please also fix it to use a minimal reproducible example like discussed under 'Help others reproduce the problem' in [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: <continued> I will add though that usually when reading a file, if it doesn't work after the first time it is because you have read in things and you didn't rest the pointer to start over. So the pointer is at the end and there is nothing else to read so it just acts as if it skipped over what worked the first time. Because of your question though having issues it is hard to tell though. For example, how does the line` while True:` related to the lines prior in regards to indenting?